# How to set Gradient color background between two thumbs in range seek bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting a MultiSlider, and I put it using "io.apptik.widget:multislider-holo:1.3" this gradle but now I want to put its color as gradient in my layout but I can't put background on thumbColor. So is there any way to fix this issue?

I tried to put the drawable in thumbColor, but it is not working and I can only put one color. But I want to put different color at both ends.

```
<io.apptik.widget.MultiSlider

              //here i want to put the gradient color  
                app:thumbColor="@drawable/abbbb"  

                app:thumbNumber="2" />
```

​[image: i want gradiant background as given image below]

Comment: Since `MultiSlider` is not a Framework widget we can not help . You need to dig into Code of this library ...

Comment: is there any other way to achive this functionallity?

Comment: @ADM that's extremely incorrect. There isn't, has never, and will never be any requirements not to ask questions on coding issues where classes aren't in the stdlib. Please don't try to direct users away from SO just for using a library, when the question appears to be otherwise fine.

Comment: Is there any way to achive this layout with multislider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this library](https://github.com/Greymamba/CusomRangebar).

Just add it's code to your XML file

Comment: implementation 'com.github.Greymamba:Rangebar:1.2.1'   this dependency provides same functionality to the problem